# Blender API: rendering a frame to memory

Tags: python, api, memory, rendering, blender

I am trying to render a frame of a scene in Blender 2.8 using the Blender Python API, where a frame output is set via:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath
```

It all works, but I was wondering can I render a frame to memory without saving an image to a disc.
I have not seen a function or property that I could use: [RenderSettings API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html#bpy.types.RenderSettings)

Such in-memory rendering output would be preferred because the rendered frames are then serialized and sent over HTTP.

Answer (score 3):

No option exists, so far.

There is an unreliable way that may suit your needs. The compositor can be setup with a viewer node which has its image contents accessible in `bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels`.

You will find a few questions on BSE, like [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/102790/935) that indicates that you can access the viewer node pixels, but there is a lack of updating that could break your workflow.

There is an [old bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T54314) about this but no fix.

As I commented in the above question, you could try creating a RAM backed [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) disk to save renders in which can eliminate diskIO.

Comment: Some years later and still no proper option to do so?